Upgrade to 24.04.1 made intune stop working
After upgrading from 24.04 to 24.04.1, intune has stopped working. Is this a known issue?
When I'm trying to install intune, I get this:
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 intune-portal : Depends: libjavascriptcoregtk-4.0-18 but it is not installable
                 Depends: libwebkit2gtk-4.0-37 (>= 2.39.90) but it is not installable


Are you sure about your details; Ubuntu 24.04 LTS is the release, the .1 is a point release which mostly refers to new ISO produced which "includes many updates and updated installation media has been provided so that fewer updates will need to be downloaded after installation" so no new install/upgrade was required; just application of normal upgrades as the system is 24.04 with .1 showing normal upgrades having been applied.  (I'm quoting from https://fridge.ubuntu.com/2024/08/30/ubuntu-24-04-1-lts-released/ or 24.04.1 release notices as they use the same text).

@guiverc Hmmm, I'm not completely sure. What I do know is that Ubuntu asked me to upgrade, that I have 24.04 and that after the upgrade, intune stopped working.

@guiverc I might mention that I had 24.04 before I as asked to upgrade.

Where did you obtain the deb package for installation?

@ArchismanPanigrahi https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/mem/intune/user-help/microsoft-intune-app-linux
